# Changing font size of plotly subplots and subplot size adjustment

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I wanted to increase the font size of the colorbar numbers for my 4 subplots in plotly (attached snapshot).

I have two questions, which I appreciate any feedback:

1. How to increase the font size of the colorbar numbers for my 4 subplots, as mentioned above, and;
   I tried update_coloraxes(colorbar_tickfont_size=30) but didnt change anything.
2. If there is any way to make the left-most subplot be as maybe three times as the other three subplots? In other words, the first subplot (which is the main plot) should be the size of 3 rows and one column, and all the other three subplots be all in one column stacked one top of each other across three rows.

Here is my code and attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# load dataset
Real_df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/volcano.csv")
Model_df = (Real_df[np.random.default_rng(seed=42).permutation(Real_df.columns.values)])
Error_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(87, 61)), columns=Real_df.columns)
Product_df = Model_df  * Error_df  



# create figure
#fig = go.Figure()

# Add surface trace

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=4,
                    specs=[[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': 
                     True}]],
                    subplot_titles=['True', 'Model', 'Error Percentage', 'Error_Model'],
                    )


fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Real_df.values.tolist(), colorscale="jet", colorbar_x=0.2), 1, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Model_df.values.tolist(), colorscale="jet", colorbar_x=0.45), 1, 2)
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Error_df.values.tolist(), colorscale="jet", colorbar_x=0.75), 1, 3)
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Product_df.values.tolist(), colorscale="jet", colorbar_x=1.05), 1, 4)
fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar_tickfont_size=90)
#fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(colorbar_thickness=2,
#        colorbar_tickfont_size=25))

# Update plot sizing
fig.update_layout(
width=800,
height=900,
autosize=False,
margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
template="plotly_white",
)

# Update plot sizing
fig.update_layout(
width=1000,
height=400,
autosize=False,
margin=dict(t=50, b=0, l=0, r=0),
template="plotly_white",
)

# Update 3D scene options
fig.update_scenes(
    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7),
    aspectmode="manual"
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

See this reference for anomalous configurations of subplots. For color bar positioning, set the names of the color bar axes in the original graph and set the x,y positions for each color bar axis. The font size of the color bar scale is also set here. Note that the color bar positions are also affected by the graph size adjustment, so it may take some trial and error to adjust the position of each color bar.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=2,
                    specs=[[{"rowspan": 3,'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}],
                           [None, {'is_3d': True}],
                           [None, {'is_3d': True}]],
                    subplot_titles=['True', 'Model', 'Error Percentage', 'Error_Model'],
                    print_grid=True,
                    )

This is the format of your plot grid:
⎡ (1,1) scene  ⎤  [ (1,2) scene2 ]
⎢      :       ⎟  [ (2,2) scene3 ]
⎣      :       ⎦  [ (3,2) scene4 ]


fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Real_df.values.tolist(), coloraxis='coloraxis'), 1, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Model_df.values.tolist(), coloraxis='coloraxis2'), 1, 2)
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Error_df.values.tolist(), coloraxis='coloraxis3'), 2, 2)
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=Product_df.values.tolist(), coloraxis='coloraxis4'), 3, 2)
fig.update_layout(coloraxis=dict(colorscale="jet", colorbar=dict(x=0.45, y=0.5, len=0.4, tickfont=dict(size=14))),
                  coloraxis2=dict(colorscale="jet", colorbar=dict(x=1.0075, y=0.85, len=0.3, tickfont=dict(size=18))),
                  coloraxis3=dict(colorscale="jet", colorbar=dict(x=1.0075, y=0.45, len=0.3, tickfont=dict(size=18))),
                  coloraxis4=dict(colorscale="jet", colorbar=dict(x=1.0075, y=0.1, len=0.3, tickfont=dict(size=18))) 
                                )

# Update plot sizing
fig.update_layout(
width=800,
height=1200,
autosize=False,
margin=dict(t=50, b=0, l=0, r=0),
template="plotly_white",
)

# Update 3D scene options
fig.update_scenes(
    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7),
    aspectmode="manual"
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it in the title declaration itself. Like this:

trace1 = go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number",    value=632,    domain={'row' : 1, 'column' : 1},
title={'text':"ICEV", 'font_size':35})